# How to change bgcolor of unselect date in FullCalendar

Tags: css, angular, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar for an Angular project. I want to change the bgcolor of the unselected date to default.

In HTML
`<full-calendar #calender [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>`

in TS:

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
 initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
 dateClick: this.onDateClick.bind(this),
 validRange: {
  start: new Date()
 },
 selectable:false
};


onDateClick(res: any) { 
  this.now=res.date;
  res.dayEl.style.backgroundColor='lightBlue';
}
```

When I click the date it changes the bgcolor to light blue for the particular date but it makes the changes to all previously selected dates. [See example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTPzw.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Full calendar already has a class for that: `.fc .fc-highlight`

Instead of using JS to set color, use css overriding.

```css
.fc .fc-highlight{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

If you are new to angular and try to use this style inside a component, it won't work without `::ng-deep{}`

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#component-styling-best-practices

Comment: ::ng-deep .fc .fc-highlight{
    background-color: lightblue;
  }  is it correct?